# Encoding issue on WebSphere 8.5.5.14 for a Java Application - XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I have this setup in my local and i am facing this error as part of inserting an xml string to an xml type column in sql table. Please review this and share your thoughts to resolve this issue.

**NOTE**: I am using SAXBuilder for xmldocument and used format.setEncoding("UTF-16") before passing that xml document as parameter.
Also to note, i dont see any such issue when i run my application using tomcat 8 and 9. I am seeing this issue only when i have integrated with WebSphere.

**Server**: Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.14
**SQL Server**: 2014
**JDBC used**: sqlJdbc41.jar and sqljdbc4.jar
**Targetted IBM JDK used**: jdk1.7_64

**Error Details**:

```
Cause SQL Exception Info for exception at level 0 - SQL State: 'S0001'; SQL Error Number: '9402'; SQL Error Text: 'XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1295)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:836)
```

Tried the following options and i did not help.

1. Updated WebSphere\AppServer\Properties\encoding.properties (WAS) file to keep this entry en=ISO-8859-1 as  en=UTF-8.
2. Also tried the above with UTF-16 as well.
3. Tried to update the following in JVC generic arguments as well.
   -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8
   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Since my application working with tomcat, so i did not expect to change any code to correct the xml string by using CAST / or passing the xmlstring with prefix N'xxxmlxx'. I will be trying this code change as well shortly. Meanwhile any other thoughts would really help.

Do i need to try with latest jdbc jar (mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre7.jar)?
Do i need to try with websphere bundled sdk 1.8?

Comment: Is your xml file read from the web request or from the file system? Are you using Tomcat and WebSphere on same machine/OS?

Comment: Thanks  \n @Gas, yes, my xml is read from a web request using file uploader. Yes i am having my Tomcat and Websphere on the same machine in my local Windows 10 Enterprise OS,

Comment: it is reading from the file system using file uploader.

Comment: Add starting fragment of your xml file to the question, to show how encoding is defined there. Also add piece of code that shows how you read file from request and pass it to the database. It looks like encoding of the file is different than encoding defined in the prolog.

Comment: before passing to executeUpdate table, the is the starting fragment of xmlstring <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> i am seeing followed by valid xml.  Will share the details on how the file is read and get the xml shortly. Thanks Gas.

Comment: before passing to executeUpdate(), the is the starting fragment of xmlstring <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> i am seeing followed by valid xml. Will share the details on how the file is read and get the xml shortly. Thanks Gas

Comment: xml file has been read using BufferedReader and write using StringBuffer and stored in a string field of a Bean and used this string variable to process. Any further thoughts would be appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: I think that setting UTF-16 encoding in `encoding.properties` should do the trick. Make sure you are doing it for correct locale, as WAS by default reads the system locale and restart the server after the changes.

Comment: I tried in setting up UTF-16 encoding for en=ISO-8859-1 in encoding.properties and no luck on this. Further, i tried to set Generic JVM Arguments as this -Dfile.encoding=UTF-16 causing websphere server starting issue. Not able to start the server, the error related to overriding.. Any further thoughts would help here..

Comment: Any idea on this 2nd point in this link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21593033 (language table and make sure that encoding is set for the language is correct).  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21593033     . Are we able see the setting in this language table by any chance?               The encoding type is also specified in the WebSphere Commerce LANGUAGE database table from the ENCODING column. Ensure this value is set to UTF-8 (or your applicable encoding type) for your language

Comment: WebSphere Commerce is different product that is based on WAS, and it has its database. What OS are you using? Did you check OS locale setting? Are you sure it is en? You can try to force en locale by using -Duser.language=en jvm custom property.

Comment: Sure, let me try that. Thanks.   I tried with my local box OS Windows 10 Enterprise and also i tried to configure with Azure VM - Windows Server 2016 as well.  Yes, the locale is en only (i could see this in request and response objects as well). Thanks again! will update once i tried. Thx Gas!

Comment: I tried with -Duser.language=en also and it seems the same issue exists. Thanks!

Comment: I'm out of ideas really. Contact IBM Support and create PMR.

Comment: Thanks Gas for all your ideas and support.